# Loop MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I have not used PHP and MySQL for some time, so I have unfortunately lost some knowledge and I need some help with my code.

Below I have some code to get 9 different values from the DB, but It doesn't work for me. And I can't tell right know what wrong because the PHP error message is set to off.

Am I way to wrong or what is wrong here?

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
$query2 = "SELECT * from arkitekturobjekt WHERE id = '{$buildingIdArray[i]}'";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result2);
// Do some stuff here
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far, but it still doesn't work! There is some wrong with the `$buildingIdArray[]` I have this code to set values to the array:

```
$buildingIdArray  = array();
$numbers = range (1, 40);
shuffle($numbers);
$buildingIdArray=array_slice ($numbers,1,9)
```

It works if I do like this:

```
$buildingIdArray  = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {....}`

Comment: Turn errormessage on when developing, testing code

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: you sure you want to query in the loop and not just compose a list of id's, query once, then loop through the results? example: WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 6, 10)

Comment: @KaiQing Could you answer with a simple code example?

Comment: @Ghillied I used that code, but nothing happened, I guess I must set the option to 'on' at my web host.

Comment: what do you get when you do something like print_r($buildingIdArray) after using your range method? By the way, first number in array slice is initial offset. You are shuffling, so it really doesn't matter, but what you're saying is grab 9 numbers beginning at the offset 1. If you intend to grab 10 like your original question, the second number should be 10 no matter what the first number is.

Comment: Hmmm, but I want 9 numbers out of 40 possible numbers....

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070581/select-random-values-from-array

Comment: It's working now! I copied the code from another answer and there was a ';' missing in the line: $buildingIdArray=array_slice ($numbers,1,9) in the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$i` not `i`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
```

Comment: It helped a lot! I have been programming in Java the last weeks, that's wy I forgot the $ sign.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I mean by my comment: "you sure you want to query in the loop and not just compose a list of id's, query once, then loop through the results? example: WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 6, 10)"

```
// get the first 10 items from building array
$id_arr = array_slice($buildingIdArray, 0, 10); 

$query2 = "SELECT * from arkitekturobjekt WHERE id IN (". implode(',', $id_arr) .")";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result2))
{
  //Do some stuff here
}
```

Keep in mind, you are still responsible for sanitization here. I don't know what populates your building id array, so if it is from $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, or anything else that could be user generated you could be open to mysql injections

Answer (score 1):

You should not run a query inside a for loop.

Use the loop to build the query and then run just one.

```
// prepare the where conditions
$where2 = Array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
  $where2[] = "`id` = '" . $buildingIdArray[$i] . "'";
}

// put the query and the conditions together
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `arkitekturobjekt` WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $where2) . ";";

// run the query and loop results
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)) {
  // do stuff with the results here
}
```